# Kernel module configuration locked built in?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to upgrade the kernel on my server for testing and when I run 
'make install' I have the errors:

```
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module crc_t10dif 
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module crct10dif_common.
```

Trying to use menuconfig I can not change the setting from built-in to module.
(Pressing N,M, or * does nothing) How can I fix this situation?

[image]

Comment: -O-, where `O` is `M` or `*` means that this option is selected by some other option, so you cannot change this one until other one is in effect. Use '?' key for know who selects you option.

Comment: @Tsyvarev That should be an answer

Comment: @GilHamilton: Yes, fixed now. Initially comment was intended as request for additional info, but during editing I have found that all info is known.

Answer (score 1):

-O-, where O is `M` or `*` means that this option is selected by some other option, so you cannot change this one until other one is in effect.

Use '?' key in `make menuconfig` mode for know who selects you option.